# C# Email - New lines not rendering with white-space: pre-wrap

Tags: c#, css, internet-explorer, outlook, html-email

I have an email with a table and one value contains a string with multiple lines. (enter-key) When viewed in outlook or view source in IE, the white-space is not working.

Any idea or any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New lines within html are not rendered as such. You need to add `<br>` tags at the end of each line to make sure that the email is rendered correctly with the new lines.

You can do this within your c# code by replacing every new line character in your problematic value with `<br>`.

Answer (score 6):

This is related to Outlook (not C#). I have the same problem (using Java to send mail). I am using CSS style `white-space:pre-wrap;` on a span and it works well to preserve tabs, spaces, new lines and wrap text in GMail - web, Android and iOS.

As per my experimentation on Outlook 2016 Windows app and webapp (outlook.office365.com):

- Value **pre-wrap** does not preserve new lines in both Windows app and webapp
- Value **pre** preserves new lines in Windows app, but does not do so in webapp

Comment: This worked for me:  const composeMessage = (message) => message?`<p id="announcements"> ${message}</p>`: '';        #announcements {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }

Comment: @Antuan what is the ` ''; #announcements { white-space: pre-wrap; } ` syntax? where am I to place it? this shows in html as well..